# Is the absolute value of a P.D.S. matrix P.D.S.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix (P.D.S.). Now consider the matrix $|A|$, the matrix arrived at by taking the absolute value of all the entries of $A$. Is $|A|$ also P.D.S.? I have been trying to construct a counter example, but I can't seem to get one. Can someone proved a proof or counterexample?

Comment: I've proven that there are no $2 \times 2$ counterexamples, but my proof doesn't adapt to any higher dimensions, since it uses the fact that a $2 \times 2$ matrix with positive trace and positive determinant has positive eigenvalues. By contrast this doesn't hold for $3 \times 3$ (consider eigenvalues of $4,-2,-1$). Interesting problem, +1.

Comment: Turns out the statement is true in dimensions 2 and 3 but fails for dimension 4 or greater. Gershgorin's circle theorem provides the insite. As a side note this problem arose from a suggestion to modify a correlation matrix in an economic model.

Comment: Could you present the proof for the $3 \times 3$ case as an additional answer? I think the $2 \times 2$ case is simple enough; the $4 \times 4$ case is in the accepted answer; and I don't think it's hard to adapt the $4 \times 4$ case to build higher examples (certainly not if you're willing to let $A$ be semidefinite). But I don't see a super-simple proof of the $3 \times 3$ case.

Comment: To prove $3\times 3$ case one could use [Sylvester criterion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersCriterion.html):
$$
A=\left[\matrix{a & d & f\\d & b & e\\f & e & c}\right]
$$
is pos.def. iff $a>0$, $ab-d^2>0$ and $abc+2def-ae^2-bf^2-cd^2>0$. Since the diagonal elements are necessarily positive, the only difference between $A$ and $|A|$ is in off-diagonal ones. It means that the only term that depends on signs is $def$ in the third condition that becomes easier to satisfy for $|A|$ since $def>0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is not true.
Here is the simulation to find a counterexample. Basically, I generate a random matrix $A$ by using normal distribution (in matlab `randn(4,4)`) and get a psd matrix $B$ by its gram matrix (`A'A`). I check the eigenvalue of absolute value of $B$.

If you do it many times, you will eventually find a counterexample. Here is one example I found and you could verify.

```
A =
   -1.8429    0.9184   -0.4437    1.2861
   -1.5589    0.7211    0.6427   -0.1817
    1.4980   -0.9764   -0.6835    0.9816
    1.1269    1.7022    1.0411   -1.0071

B =
    9.3402   -2.3612   -0.0349   -1.7512
   -2.3612    5.2145    2.4954   -1.6227
   -0.0349    2.4954    2.1610   -2.4070
   -1.7512   -1.6227   -2.4070    3.6650
```

The eigenvalues of $B$,

```
d = 
    0.0865
    1.7064
    7.9794
   10.6082
```

The eigenvalues of $|B|$,

```
d_abs =
   -0.1351
    2.7554
    6.2533
   11.5070
```

I'm interested if there are more elegant ways to disprove the statement.

Comment: How many attempts did you need to find this? I have just tried maybe 40 times and I get positive definite results each time.

Comment: It only took me 11 times (it depends, experimentally on average less than 100 times). Make sure you use normal distribution but not `rand` if you use matlab.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to abs. Silly mistake; now I found it in 56 iterations, and then in 18 after that.

Comment: It seems that the important feature is that there is a pair of relatively large negative off-diagonal elements in $B$. I have a three significant digit example: $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1.75 & 0.59 & -0.92 & 0.67 \\ 0.59 & 10.7 & -0.06 & -3.97 \\ -0.92 & -0.06 & 0.52 & -0.42 \\ 0.67 & -3.97 & -0.42 & 2.28 \end{bmatrix}$. Here the effect appears to be driven by the $-3.97$, in the sense that if you flip *only* those signs the result is already indefinite. This makes a degree of sense from the perspective of continuity of eigenvalues.

Comment: BTW using `B=randi([-1,1],4,4);A=B'*B` gives "nicer" examples.

Answer (score 4):

One counterexample could be
$$
A=\left[\matrix{10 & 3 & -2 & 1\\3 & 10 & 0 & 9\\-2 & 0 & 10 & 4\\1 & 9 & 4 & 10}\right].
$$
$A$ is positive-definite, however $|A|$ is not positive-semidefinite.

Another one:
$$
A=\left[\matrix{1.5 & 1 & 0 & -1\\1 & 1.5 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1.5 & 1\\-1 & 0 & 1 & 1.5}\right].
$$