# Why this matrix is not a distance matrix?

Tags: metric-spaces

While working on [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355088/is-the-absolute-value-of-a-p-d-s-matrix-p-d-s), I came across the following matrix
$$D=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&2\\
1&0&\sqrt 2&1\\
1&\sqrt 2&0&1\\
2&1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
This matrix comes from the following:
$$D_{ij}=D_{ji}=\sqrt{K_{ii}+K_{jj}-2|K_{ij}|},$$
where $K=XX^\top$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\1&0\\0&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, my question is: why $D$ is not a distance matrix ?
It's obviously not a distance matrix, as its square has more than one positive eigenvalue. But at the same time:

1. It is symmetric
2. $D_{ij}=0 \iff i=j$
3. The triangle inequality is obviously satisfied, since $D_{ij}\le 2 \le D_{ik}+D_{kj}$.

So, what's going on here ?

Comment: Why can't it have more than 1 positive eigenvalue?

Comment: And what is diag supposed to mean? If working on a matrix it produces a vector with diagonal elements in it, no? You can't add a vector to a matrix.

Comment: Diag is a shortcut used in Matlab. Diag(K) is the column vector with entries equal to the diagonal of K. Sure you can't add vectors and matrix, I should have written $D_{ij} = K_{ii}^2+K_{jj}^2...$

Comment: Also, distance matrices always have exactly one positive eigenvalue. If not, it means that $K$ is not positive semi definite, thus does not describe a metric.

Comment: What is $K$...?

Comment: $K=XX^\top$, the kernel matrix

Comment: Wait, $K_{ii}^2$? Then you are missing a square. If not $K^2 = XX^T$

Comment: Ooooh... I made a mistake in the comments while answering on my phone. I edit the post for more clarity.

Comment: But now the absolute value on the last term disappeared, is it supposed to be there?

Comment: Sorry. I added it back. In fact, when you compute a distance using this kernel trick, there is no absolute value, of course. But the previous topic asked if $K\succeq 0 \implies |K|\succeq 0$. If the answer is yes, then $|K|$ should also be the kernel of some space. That's why you have the absoluve value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel is only positive semi-definite if the metric is Euclidean. And indeed, the distances in your matrix are not achievable in that case. But consider the following points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, equipped with the metric obtained from the maximum norm, $d(x,y) = max(|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|)$:

- $p_1=(0,0)$,
- $p_2=(1,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$,
- $p_3=(1,-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$,
- $p_4=(2,0)$.

These do achieve $d(p_i,p_j) = D_{ij}$.

Comment: So, basically, the data points are on a manifold. Is it possible to "unfold" this manifold ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unfold".

Comment: I know "unfold" is very vague. But, for example, you can obtain an Euclidean representation of a graph, that gives you the commute-time distance between nodes of this graph. In the example given by the matrix $D$, I don't really know what "unfold" would mean. I think I'm trying to figure what is the interpretation of the negative eigenvalues of the kernel associated with $D$.

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm not sure what can be done in this direction, sorry.

Comment: Hi davcha, do you mean like to draw a map? To parametrize a curve or surface?